# Breadth First Search question C++

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

This is my first time programming C++ and I've been asked to code a breadth first search where given this class

```
class route {

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const route& p);

 public:

  route(const string& startPlayer);
  int getLength() const { return links.size(); };
  void addConnect(const sport& s, const string& player);
  void removeConnect();
  const string& getLastPlayer() const;

 private:

  struct Connect {
    sport s;
    string player;
    Connect() {}
    Connect(const sport& s, const string& player) : s(s), player(player) {}
  };

  string startPlayer;
  vector<Connect> links;
};
```

`sport` is a struct consisting of `string name` and `int players`. Could someone explain to me how I'd go about making the BFS?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I understand the algorithm for BFS, but since I've only ever programmed C, understanding OO programming is quite confusing to me, given that interface, where do I start with this BFS, do I make a new function which makes the BFS comparing, the `start string` with the `target string`

```
namespace {

string promptForSPlayer(const string& prompt, const spdb& db)
{
  string response;
  while (true) {
    cout << prompt << " [or <enter> to quit]: ";
    getline(cin, response);
    if (response == "") return "";
    vector<sport> splist;
    if (db.getsplist(response, splist)) return response;
    cout << "It's not here: \"" << response << "\" in the sports database. "
     << "Please try again." << endl;
  }
}

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2) {
    cerr << "Usage: sports" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  spdb db(argv[1]);

  if (!db.good()) {
    cout << "Failed to properly initialize the spdb database." << endl;
    cout << "Please check to make sure the start files exist and that you have permission to read them." << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  while (true) {
    string start = promptForSplayer("Player", db);
    if (start == "") break;
    string target = promptForSplayer("Another Player", db);
    if (target == "") break;
    if (start == target) {
      cout << "Good one.  This is only interesting if you specify two different people." << endl;
    } else {
      // replace the following line by a call to your generateShortestPath routine... 
      cout << endl << "No path between those two people could be found." << endl << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The algorithm is laid out pretty well in pseudo-code here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because im confused as how to start

Comment: Confused about programming in C++?

Comment: What are you confused about specifically? "OO programming" is a broad topic.

Comment: yeah, do i call the connect struct, check the player with the player inputted by the user? and follow on with the algorithm in that sense?

Comment: edited the first post to be more precise in what i am asking

Comment: What is the purpose of your connect struct - to add players to the path to be searched? Can you be certain that there is only 1 path to each player? If not, you must be certain to have a way to mark each player as "touched" by the search (so you don't add them multiple times to your queue). If you know where your list is, you can probably follow the algorithm directly it seems.

Answer (score 4):

Breadth First search is all about asking 2 questions

1. What state am I at right now?
2. What states can I get to from here?

The idea is to have an initial state and continuously ask yourself these 2 questions until

1. No more states left.
2. I have reached the destination state.

BFS usually uses a Queue to which you simply add any new states you find and simply pop from the front of the queue whenever you want to process a new state and add any new states to the end of the queue.

Comment: Breadth-first and Depth-first are almost exactly the same algorithm.  One uses a LIFO stack, the other a FIFO queue.  Other than that, they're identical.

Answer (score 0):

The route class is only a mechanism to store the routes that you find using BFS. At least that's how I'm interpreting it. The BFS algorithm will be a stand alone function that will call methods of the route class at appropiate times. Since a BFS needs to maintain information about multiple routes it will have to create multiple route objects in some sort of list or queue. Each step of the BFS will take one route object from the queue, copy it and call addConnect on it to move to the next location, then place it back on the queue. Repeat until you get to your destination, then return the route object representing the shortest path from your BFS function.

Something like that anyway.